# What is short pseudocode for determining the total number of bitcoins mined?

Tags: block, mining-reward

Here's what I have so far:

```
total_epochs = current_block_height % 210000
total_coins = 0;

for(i = 1; i <= total_epochs; i++) {
  reward = 100 / 2^(i * 210000 / 210000);
  total_coins += 210000 * reward;
}
```

But this overaccounts for the total coins. Any simpler strategy that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a\b representing integer division and a%b the remainder of this division:

```
  blocks_per_epoch = 210000;
  initial_reward = 5 * 10^9;

  current_epoch = current_block_height \ blocks_per_epoch;
  blocks_in_current_epoch = (current_block_height % blocks_per_epoch) + 1;
  current_reward = initial_reward / 2 ^ (current_epoch);

  total_coins = 2 * blocks_per_epoch * (initial_reward - current_reward) +
     blocks_in_current_epoch * current_reward;
```

Note that this can be off by a few satoshis due to a different rounding.

If you work with integers for the reward, the division for current_reward can be replaced with a bitshift. If not, you can change initial_reward to 50 to give result in BTC instead of satoshis.

Comment: Hmmmm - doesn't seem to work. Given that block `147751` is used as the current height (I know we're past that - but work with me here).

current_epoch = 147751 \ 210000 = 0
blocks_in_current_epoch = 147752;
current_reward = 25
total_coins = 14193800

This is definitely off

Comment: @Shamoon: current_reward in this case is 50, not 25.

Comment: How? if `current_epoch` is 0, then initial_reward / 2^0 would be 50 / 1 = 50

Comment: @Shamoon - Yes.

Comment: Actually - this is off by one block. For block `38,330`, it's `1,916,550 BTC`, but it should be: `1916500`

Comment: @Shamoon - No. The first block has height 0. So if the current block height (as in: The height of the last block found) is 0, there are 50 BTC. If the height is 38,330, there are 1916550 BTC. If you want current_block_height to represent the number of existing blocks ( = the height of the next block) instead, remove the +1 for blocks_in_current_epoch.